# Can we change single digit values to multiple digits using SQL?

Tags: sql

i have a table with values 1,2,3 etc and also multiple digits values. how can i convert all the single digits to multiple digits by adding zero in the left side? I used CAST, CONVERT functions but it doesn't give the desired output. Can anyone please suggest any methods..

Thanks

Comment: Please tag with the actual database you are using.  Note that integers/numbers etc. do not actually have zeroes to the left of the leftmost significant digit.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Sql Server. Since 2012 version you can use [FORMAT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
select
  num,
  format(num,'00')
from (
  values (0),(3),(9),(10),(99),(100)
) x (num)
```